# Garbage collection of destroyed Activities / Destruction of old Activities

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

While studying Activities, I was surprised to see that they were not destroyed and garbage collected (GC) even under high memory pressure (tested on Samsung GT-l9505, Android 4.4.2)

I wrote a simple Activity, containing an `ImageView` (with associated Bitmap of ~16Mb) and a `Button` to test a few things. Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private byte[] hugeMemoryUse;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        Log.d("test_activity", "Activity created");
        super.onCreate(saved);
        hugeMemoryUse = new byte[10 * 1000 * 1000];
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.huge_image);
        Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images)).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,bmp.getWidth()*3,bmp.getHeight()*3,false);
        Log.d("test_activity","Width = " + bmp2.getWidth() + ", Height = "  + bmp2.getHeight());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
        button.setText("click to add activity");
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (isFinishing()) {
            Log.d("test_activity", "Finishing");
        }
        Log.d("test_activity", "Activity stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("test_activity", "Activity destroyed");
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, I create a new `MainActivity` on top of the current one. As you can see, the Activity also holds a reference to a 10Mb byte array. This reference is not cleared on purpose.

Now, if I press the button multiple times, the application will eventually crash with an OutOfMemoryException. Here is the log when I click the button multiple times:

```
07-31 12:06:44.919  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:06:44.939  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 35% free 17261K/26284K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-31 12:06:44.949  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 30.263MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:44.999  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 21% free 28831K/36052K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
07-31 12:06:45.019  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 48.618MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:45.029  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:06:48.473  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:06:48.483  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1794K, 18% free 43057K/52020K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
07-31 12:06:48.503  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 54.455MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:48.533  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 12% free 54610K/61788K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-31 12:06:48.563  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 71.792MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:48.573  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:06:48.843  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:06:54.478  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:06:54.488  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1786K, 12% free 68821K/77756K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
07-31 12:06:54.519  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 79.615MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:54.559  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 9% free 80374K/87524K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
07-31 12:06:54.579  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.953MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:54.589  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:06:54.889  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:06:56.530  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:06:56.560  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1789K, 9% free 94584K/103492K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
07-31 12:06:56.581  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 104.774MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:56.611  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 7% free 106137K/113260K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-31 12:06:56.641  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 122.112MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:56.651  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:06:56.831  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:06:57.912  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:06:57.932  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1785K, 7% free 120347K/129228K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
07-31 12:06:57.932  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:06:57.972  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 14K, 7% free 120333K/129228K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
07-31 12:06:57.972  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 10000016-byte allocation.
07-31 12:06:57.972  27401-27401/test.testactivitygc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: test.testactivitygc, PID: 27401
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at test.testactivitygc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

One can see that each time I create a new Activity, 26 Mb are allocated on the Heap (10 Mb for the byte array and 16 Mb for the Bitmap). While the Heap grows larger, I would expect Android to destroy Activties on the stack.

BUT ! **The Activities on the stack are not destroyed !** They remain here and the Bitmap and byte array are not destroyed. Even when the process runs very low on Memory. That is not what I expected from Android. **Why is that the case ?** Also, I know that good practice would require us to clear unused references (in onPause, onStop or onDestroy), but here `onDestroy` is not even called.

On the other hand, when I change the orientation of the screen, the Activity get destroyed. The Heap still grows larger, but eventually becomes stable, when the oldest Activity is GC I guess.

Here is one iteration when Heap is stable :

```
07-31 12:18:08.816    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:18:08.816    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity destroyed
07-31 12:18:08.826    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
07-31 12:18:08.826    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
07-31 12:18:08.826    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:18:08.836    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 27540K, 34% free 68806K/103488K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
07-31 12:18:08.836    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 79.601MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:18:08.876    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 23% free 80357K/103488K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
07-31 12:18:08.886    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.936MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:18:08.886    7797-7797/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
```

Finally, **I checked the option "Do not keep activities"** under developer options of the phone. The old Activity is destroyed consistently, but here again, **the Heap grows and eventually becomes stable**. Here is the log :

```
07-31 12:23:05.326  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:23:05.346  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 63K, 35% free 17261K/26284K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-31 12:23:05.356  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 30.263MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:05.406  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 21% free 28831K/36052K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
07-31 12:23:05.436  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 48.618MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:05.446  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:23:08.108  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:23:08.128  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1796K, 18% free 43056K/52020K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-31 12:23:08.148  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 54.455MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:08.188  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 12% free 54609K/61788K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
07-31 12:23:08.218  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 71.792MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:08.218  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:23:08.509  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:23:08.519  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity destroyed
07-31 12:23:10.060  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:23:10.090  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1787K, 12% free 68819K/77756K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
07-31 12:23:10.110  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 79.614MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:10.150  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15K, 9% free 80363K/87524K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
07-31 12:23:10.180  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.942MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:10.180  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:23:10.461  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:23:10.471  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity destroyed
07-31 12:23:11.452  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:23:11.482  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1790K, 9% free 94572K/103492K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
07-31 12:23:11.502  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 104.763MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:11.542  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25768K, 30% free 80363K/113260K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-31 12:23:11.542  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.943MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:11.552  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
07-31 12:23:11.842  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity stopped
07-31 12:23:11.852  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity destroyed
07-31 12:23:15.646  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Activity created
07-31 12:23:15.666  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1787K, 17% free 94573K/113260K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
07-31 12:23:15.666  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 104.763MB for 10000016-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:15.696  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25768K, 30% free 80363K/113260K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
07-31 12:23:15.706  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 96.943MB for 16350028-byte allocation
07-31 12:23:15.716  13512-13512/test.testactivitygc D/test_activity﹕ Width = 2403, Height = 1701
```

Now, I would like to know if this could be explain due to process differences ? As I'm testing the application, I guess that the memory management could be a bit different. (Here i'm not debugging, just running the app).
I was told that there were big differences between new and old versions of Android. But why does Android prefer to crash instead of garbaging some old Activities ?

So what would be the correct way to handle that? Manually release each reference in onPause/onStop ?

Comment: There's no reason to free/recreate resources when the system isn't low on memory, that would be wasted cycles, especially for big objects. This would also make navigation between apps less snappy. I think that it's best to release resources when `Activity#onLowMemory()` is called, rather than freeing/recreating them on each pause/resume. As for the main question, I am not sure if that's the thought behind the observed behavior.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for pointing out onLowMemory. Unfortunately, as I understand it, it's not usable in that case. Even onTrimMemory is not useful. First, because the callback is called only when the process is in background. Second, because it seems that it will only be called when the overall process in low on memory. As mentioned on android developer:  "This will happen for example when it goes in the background and there is not enough memory to keep as many background processes running as desired."

I overrode the two callbacks and they were not called when the application was in foreground.